# How do you transfer data from a table to a server?

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch data from a table and push the selected data to my server.
I have tried selecting columns from my table then making an HTTP request, but it didn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what you are asking is too broad

Comment: Could you share what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to pull data from a HTML table, put it into a  javascript array, convert it to json and send it to the server

https://jsfiddle.net/f958qokn/

```
<table id="MyTable">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Code Monkey</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Code Elephpant</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input id="PostTableData" type="button" value="Post Table Data"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#PostTableData" ).on( "click", function() {
var TableData = [];

$("#MyTable tr").each(function() {
    var RowData = [];
    var ColumnsData = $(this).find('td');
    if (ColumnsData.length > 0) {
        ColumnsData.each(function() { RowData.push($(this).text()); });
        TableData.push(RowData);
    }
});
alert(JSON.stringify(TableData)); 
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/SaveData.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(TableData),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){ alert(data); }
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding

here is a procedure if you like to do

1. insert all you desire record set into an array
2. make a json using json_encode() method of php.
3. use curl post request and pass the json string